# ReGex Help -- extracting the number beside the word

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP, I need to know how to obtain the number that's beside the phrase "Page count:". Here's how the output looks like.

```
$string = 'Author: Microtest Windows Version 1.1
Creation time: 2016-02-12 02:51:00
Last modified by: Some Name
Last modification time: 2016-02-12 15:51:00
Page count: 14
Word count: 5142';
```

In this case, I want to store the page count as $page_number. I.e.

```
echo $page_number; --> 14
```

How would I do this using REGEX

Comment: `Page count: (\d+)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regex:** `/Page count:\s*\K\d+/`

1. `Page count:\s*` to match `Page count:` with 0 or more spaces.
2. `\K` to reset current match.
3. `\d+` for grabbing digits.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779356)

```
<?php
$string = 'Author: Microtest Windows Version 1.1
Creation time: 2016-02-12 02:51:00
Last modified by: Some Name
Last modification time: 2016-02-12 15:51:00
Page count: 14
Word count: 5142';
preg_match("/Page count:\s*\K\d+/", $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
)
```

Comment: That did it.

    echo $matches[0];

Comment: @stylusss Yes, `echo $matches[0];` with give you, what you want. page_count